# perl in different locations on different sites

Tags: perl

I have a lot of perl scripts. I will be supporting multiple sites which might not have the same perl paths (shebang line).

How can I avoid changing the top shebang line in each of the perl scripts?

This is all in the unix environment.

regards,
Gordon

Comment: Your question is not about different versions of perl. Your question is about different locations of perl.

Comment: Edited question/title to specify "locations" and "paths" rather than "versions".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual solution is to use the [`env`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/env-invocation.html) command:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
```

Comment: I also use this to ensure that I use site perl rather than system perl, which is usually not the one you want to run with, as system updates can have unintended consequences.

Comment: I use this, too, but it has issues.  You cannot put options after the word perl on all systems.